# Hi, Can someone please explain how I can increase my coverage, currently at 40% but need 75%? I moved the test up to line 105 worked well

Tags: apex, trigger, code-coverage

CURRENT TRIGGER

```
trigger FX_Ticket_OnAfter on FX5__Ticket__c (after insert, after update) {
    Boolean stopTrigger = false;
    FX5__Status__c readyForInvStatus = null;
    Map<Id,List<FX5__Ticket_Item__c>> readyForInvTktItemMap = new Map<Id,List<FX5__Ticket_Item__c>>();
    
    // Sequences the Ticket Items when a Ticket has been moved to the "Ready_for_Invoicing" status
    try {   
        readyForInvStatus = [select Id,Name,Status_Developer_Name__c from FX5__Status__c where FX5__SObject__c='Ticket__c' and Status_Developer_Name__c='Ready_for_Invoicing' LIMIT 1];
    }
    catch (System.QueryException e) {
        // This Stop Trigger catch was added so that ticket unit tests won't fail when no statuses are inserted as part of the test.
        stopTrigger = true;
    }
    
    if (!stopTrigger) {  
        // find the Ready for Invoicing tickets that need their ticket items sequenced.
        for(FX5__Ticket__c t : trigger.new) {
            if (readyforInvStatus != null && t.FX5__Status__c != null && t.FX5__Status__c == readyForInvStatus.Id) {
                readyForInvTktItemMap.put(t.Id,new List<FX5__Ticket_Item__c>());
            }
        }
        string sortText = FX5__FX_Settings__c.getOrgDefaults().TicketItemSort__c;
        if(sortText == null) sortText = 'FX5__Ticket__c,Record_Type_Sort_Index__c,Name';
        
        if (readyForInvTktItemMap.size() > 0) {
            // finish out the map of Ticket Item Sets for sequencing
            /*List<FX5__Ticket_Item__c> tktItems = [
select 
Id,FX5__Ticket__c,FX5__Sequence_Number__c,
EXPRO_SAP_Item_Number__c,
Record_Type_Sort_Index__c
from 
FX5__Ticket_Item__c 
where 
FX5__Ticket__c in :readyForInvTktItemMap.keySet()
order by 
FX5__Ticket__c,Record_Type_Sort_Index__c,Name];
*/
            set<id> readyForInvTktItemSet = readyForInvTktItemMap.keySet();
            string query = 'select ';
            query += 'Id,FX5__Ticket__c,FX5__Sequence_Number__c,EXPRO_SAP_Item_Number__c,Record_Type_Sort_Index__c ';
            query += 'from FX5__Ticket_Item__c ';
            query += 'where FX5__Ticket__c in :readyForInvTktItemSet ';
            query += 'order by ' + sortText;
            
            List<FX5__Ticket_Item__c> tktItems = database.query(query);
            
            if (tktItems != null) {
                for(FX5__Ticket_Item__c tktItem : tktItems) {
                    readyForInvTktItemMap.get(tktItem.FX5__Ticket__c).add(tktItem);
                }
                
                // Sequence the Ticket Items in the list
                List<FX5__Ticket_Item__c> tktItemsToUpdate = new List<FX5__Ticket_Item__c>();
                for(Id tktId : readyForInvTktItemMap.keySet()) {
                    Integer seq = 10;
                    for(FX5__Ticket_Item__c tktItem : readyForInvTktItemMap.get(tktId)) {
                        tktItem.EXPRO_SAP_Item_Number__c = seq;
                        seq = seq + 10;
                        tktItemsToUpdate.add(tktItem);  
                    }
                }
                
                update tktItemsToUpdate;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

CURRENT TEST CLASS

```
@isTest
private class FX_Ticket_OnAfter_Test {
    
    public class TestData {
        public Map<String, RecordType> tirtMap;
        public FX5__Status__c newTicketStatus;
        public FX5__Status__c readyForInvStatus;
        public List<FX5__Catalog_Item__c> ciList;
        public List<FX5__Price_Book_Item__c> pbiList;
        
        public String GetDefaultUOMForRecordType(String rtDeveloperName) {
            if (rtDeveloperName == 'Daily_Personnel' || rtDeveloperName == 'Daily_Equipment')
                return 'Day';
            if (rtDeveloperName == 'Hourly_Equipment' || rtDeveloperName == 'Hourly_Personnel')
                return 'Hour';
            return 'Each';
        }
        
        public void ProvisionTestData(FX_UnitTestHelper.ExproJob_LocalTestData mockData) {
            this.newTicketStatus = new FX5__Status__c(
                Name = 'New Ticket',
                FX5__SObject__c = 'Ticket__c',
                Status_Developer_Name__c = 'New_Ticket');
            this.readyForInvStatus = new FX5__Status__c(
                Name = 'Ready for Invoicing',
                FX5__SObject__c = 'Ticket__c',
                Status_Developer_Name__c = 'Ready_for_Invoicing');
            insert this.newTicketStatus;
            insert this.readyForInvStatus;      
            
            this.tirtMap = new Map<String,RecordType>();
            this.ciList = new List<FX5__Catalog_Item__c>();
            Integer ciCount = 1;
            for (RecordType tirt : [select Id,DeveloperName from RecordType where IsActive=true and SobjectType='FX5__Ticket_Item__c']) {
                this.tirtMap.put(tirt.DeveloperName,tirt);
                this.ciList.add(new FX5__Catalog_Item__c(
                    Name = String.valueOf(ciCount) + '-0135',
                    FX5__IsArchived__c = false,
                    FX5__Description__c = 'Test Item ' + String.valueOf(ciCount),
                    EXPRO_SAP_Plant__c = '0135',
                    FX5__Sequence_Number__c = ciCount,
                    FX5__Ticket_Item_Record_Type__c = tirt.DeveloperName,
                    FX5__UOM__c = GetDefaultUOMForRecordType(tirt.DeveloperName)
                ));
                ciCount += 1;
                this.ciList.add(new FX5__Catalog_Item__c(
                    Name = String.valueOf(ciCount) + '-0135',
                    FX5__IsArchived__c = false,
                    FX5__Description__c = 'Test Item ' + String.valueOf(ciCount),
                    EXPRO_SAP_Plant__c = '0135',
                    FX5__Sequence_Number__c = ciCount,
                    FX5__Ticket_Item_Record_Type__c = tirt.DeveloperName,
                    FX5__UOM__c = this.GetDefaultUOMForRecordType(tirt.DeveloperName)
                ));
                ciCount += 1;
            }
            insert this.ciList;
            
            Set<Id> ciIdSet = new Set<Id>();
            for (FX5__Catalog_Item__c ci : ciList) {
                insert (new FX5__Price_Book_Item__c(
                    FX5__Price_Book__c = mockData.testPriceBook.Id,
                    FX5__IsArchived__c = false,
                    FX5__Catalog_Item__c = ci.Id,
                    FX5__Default_Quantity__c = 0,
                    FX5__Price__c = 100));
                ciIdSet.add(ci.Id);
            }
            // We want to fetch the Price Book Items back after insertion so that we get the result of all triggers that fired
            this.pbiList = [
                select 
                Id,FX5__Price_Book__c,FX5__Catalog_Item__c,FX5__IsArchived__c,FX5__Default_Quantity__c,FX5__Price__c,
                FX5__Ticket_Item_Record_Type__c,FX5__Sequence_Number__c,FX5__Catalog_Item__r.FX5__Ticket_Item_Record_Type__c
                from FX5__Price_Book_Item__c where FX5__Catalog_Item__c in :ciIdSet];
        }
    }
    
    static testMethod void TestTicketItemSequencingForSAP() {
        FX_UnitTestHelper.ExproJob_LocalTestData mockData = new FX_UnitTestHelper.ExproJob_LocalTestData();
        mockData.ProvisionTestData(true);
        TestData testData = new TestData();
        testData.ProvisionTestData(mockData);
        
        List<FX5__Ticket__c> tktList = FX_UnitTestHelper.CreateTickets(mockData.testJob, 2, true);
        FX5__Ticket__c readyForInvTicket = tktList.get(0);
        FX5__Ticket__c newTicket = tktList.get(1);
        
        List<FX5__Ticket_Item__c> testTktItems = new List<FX5__Ticket_Item__c>();
        // Add ticket items to the each mock ticket
        for (FX5__Ticket__c tkt : tktList) {
            for (FX5__Price_Book_Item__c pbi : testData.pbiList) {
                RecordType tiRT = testData.tirtMap.get(pbi.FX5__Catalog_Item__r.FX5__Ticket_Item_Record_Type__c);
                testTktItems.add(new FX5__Ticket_Item__c(
                    FX5__Ticket__c = tkt.Id,
                    FX5__Price_Book_Item__c = pbi.Id,
                    RecordTypeId = tiRT.Id));
            }
        }
        insert testTktItems;
        
        Test.startTest();
        
        newTicket.FX5__Status__c = testData.newTicketStatus.Id;
        readyForInvTicket.FX5__Status__c = testData.readyForInvStatus.Id;
        
        update newTicket;      
        update readyForInvTicket;
        
        Test.stopTest();
        
        List<FX5__Ticket_Item__c> newTicketItems = [select Id,FX5__Ticket__c,EXPRO_SAP_Item_Number__c from FX5__Ticket_Item__c where FX5__Ticket__c = :newTicket.Id];
        // Ensure that Ticket items on the "New Ticket" items did not update EXPRO_SAP_Item_Number__c
        for (FX5__Ticket_Item__c tktItem : newTicketItems) {
            System.assert(tktItem.EXPRO_SAP_Item_Number__c == null, 'Expected null for EXPRO_SAP_Item_Number__c on "New Ticket" Ticket Item.');
        } 
        
        List<FX5__Ticket_Item__c> readyForInvTicketItems = [select Id,FX5__Ticket__c,EXPRO_SAP_Item_Number__c,Record_Type_Sort_Index__c,RecordTypeId from FX5__Ticket_Item__c where FX5__Ticket__c = :readyForInvTicket.Id order by EXPRO_SAP_Item_Number__c];
        System.assert(readyForInvTicketItems.size() > 0);
        for (Integer i=0; i < readyForInvTicketItems.size(); i+=1) {
            FX5__Ticket_Item__c ti = readyForInvTicketItems.get(i);
            System.assertEquals((i+1)*10, ti.EXPRO_SAP_Item_Number__c);
        }
    }
    
    /*
* This test ensures that a Ticket that does not have a status will not crash the Ticket On After trigger and will not cause any other 
* unit tests to fail that do not have a status reference. 
*/
    static testMethod void TestInsertTicketWithNullStatus() {
        FX_UnitTestHelper.ExproJob_LocalTestData mockData = new FX_UnitTestHelper.ExproJob_LocalTestData();
        mockData.ProvisionTestData(true);
        
        RecordType ftRT = [select Id,DeveloperName from RecordType where IsActive=true and SobjectType='FX5__Ticket__c' and DeveloperName='Field_Ticket'];
        FX5__Ticket__c t = new FX5__Ticket__c(
            FX5__Job__c = mockData.testJob.Id,
            RecordTypeId = ftRT.Id
        );
        
        Test.startTest();
        insert t;        
        Test.stopTest();
        
        System.assertEquals(1,([select Id from FX5__Ticket__c where FX5__Job__c = :mockData.testJob.Id]).size());
    }
    
}
```

Comment: SFDCFox, Thanks but I am now at 37% instead of 40%

Comment: I moved the test further up to line 105 this has worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the surface area of your code by optimizing out some parts:

```
trigger FX_Ticket_OnAfter on FX5__Ticket__c (after insert, after update) {
    FX5__Status__c readyForInvStatus;
    // Sequences the Ticket Items when a Ticket has been moved to the "Ready_for_Invoicing" status
    try {
        readyForInvStatus = [select Id,Name,Status_Developer_Name__c from FX5__Status__c where FX5__SObject__c='Ticket__c' and Status_Developer_Name__c='Ready_for_Invoicing' LIMIT 1];
    } catch (System.QueryException e) {
        // This Stop Trigger catch was added so that ticket unit tests won't fail when no statuses are inserted as part of the test.
        return;
    }
    Map<Id,List<FX5__Ticket_Item__c>> readyForInvTktItemMap = new Map<Id,List<FX5__Ticket_Item__c>>();
    // find the Ready for Invoicing tickets that need their ticket items sequenced.
    for(FX5__Ticket__c t : trigger.new) {
        if (t.FX5__Status__c == readyForInvStatus.Id) {
            readyForInvTktItemMap.put(t.Id,new List<FX5__Ticket_Item__c>());
        }
    }
    if(readyForInvTktItemMap.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    string sortText = FX5__FX_Settings__c.getOrgDefaults().TicketItemSort__c;
    if(sortText == null) {
        sortText = 'FX5__Ticket__c,Record_Type_Sort_Index__c,Name';
    }
    set<id> readyForInvTktItemSet = readyForInvTktItemMap.keySet();
    string query = 'select '
        + 'FX5__Ticket__c,FX5__Sequence_Number__c,EXPRO_SAP_Item_Number__c,Record_Type_Sort_Index__c '
        + 'from FX5__Ticket_Item__c ';
        + 'where FX5__Ticket__c in :readyForInvTktItemSet ';
        + 'order by ' 
        + sortText;
    
    List<FX5__Ticket_Item__c> tktItemsToUpdate = database.query(query);
    for(FX5__Ticket_Item__c tktItem : tktItemsToUpdate) {
        readyForInvTktItemMap.get(tktItem.FX5__Ticket__c).add(tktItem);
    }
    // Sequence the Ticket Items in the list
    for(Id tktId : readyForInvTktItemMap.keySet()) {
        Integer seq = 0;
        for(FX5__Ticket_Item__c tktItem : readyForInvTktItemMap.get(tktId)) {
            tktItem.EXPRO_SAP_Item_Number__c = seq = seq + 10;
        }
    }
    update tktItemsToUpdate;
}
```

From there, you just need to make sure you have a unit test for when `FX5__FX_Settings__c.getOrgDefaults().TicketItemSort__c` is null, and you need a unit test for when no records match the readyForInvStatus at all.

Comment: Thanks but this has reduced the coverage to 37% I am quite new to this so struggling a little.

Comment: I moved the test further up to line 105 this has worked.